# Bind DNS Server set root NS

Tags: linux, networking, dns

I will setup a local DNS server for domains under my authority. I will configure this DNS server as default on my LAN.

Say there is a DNS request for a domain outside my authority. From what I know my DNS will escalate this to the next zone (above). How can I configure BIND to escalate these request to a specific DNS Server (say 8.8.8.8)

Answer (score 1):

For what i can see you want to enable forwarding, make sure  `BIND` is configured recursive `recursion yes;`.

For a forwarding example see:

https://serverfault.com/questions/98510/bind-dns-forwarding-for-external-domain

Answer (score 0):

This configuration snippet should do exactly what you need in terms of forwarding:

```
acl auth_nets {
        192.168.1/24;
        127.0.0/8;
};

options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";
        version "Do you mind?";
        forward only;
        forwarders {
                8.8.8.8;
        };
        allow-query { auth_nets; };
        allow-recursion { auth_nets; };
};
```

Note that the `forward only` option instructs `bind` to rely only on forwarders for external domains resolution requests. `auth_nets` is a custom acl I set up for security reasons, since I wanted to impose a restriction on which hosts can query my DNS server (and use it recursively).